# Autocomplete javascript/DOM API in vim?

Tags: vim, autocomplete

I always make typos when typing the long function names like `ctx.createRadialGradient`. It will be great if I can autocomplete them.

1. Is there any plugin I can use out of the box?
2. If not, how to add new custom keywords for vim's autocompletion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In insert mode exists command <kbd>Ctrl-X</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-P</kbd> to complete with previous matches. So if you have:

```
ctx.createRadialGradient
ctx.createGradient
ctx.create
```

and begin to write `ctx.cr`, press <kbd>Ctrl-X</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-P</kbd> and those strings will appear in a context window, you can navigate throught them with arrow keys or with <kbd>Ctrl-N</kbd> for Next or <kbd>Ctrl-P</kbd> for Previous.